# Android: How to apply a variable to a toast?

Tags: java, android

I'm going to be using a toast in my application for testing purposes. I am only new to the Android environment and I'm not very familiar with toasts. I know a standard toast it like this: `Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();`. However, instead of applying a String of text into the 'text' section, I want to apply a variable.

Here is what I have written:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_next);


    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);//Import button1 (Send)

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {//Set an onClickListener for the button to work

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }//end method

    });//End Send


}//End onCreate
```

`cText` is a variable used in a different method present in the class. Any suggestions on how I can get the toast to contain the contents of `cText`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the type of `cText`? Is it local to the other method?

Comment: What kind of variables? An Int? Use Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value: " + yourInt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Comment: Simply put cText is out of scope and you will not be able to do this.  What you could do is store cText globally and reference that variable but this is not generally considered good practice.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cText.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 2):

May be you an Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String Text="MainActivity  Message"; //Global variable

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_next);
 Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);//Import button1 (Send)

    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {//Set an onClickListener for the button to work

    public void onClick(View v) {

       //Declaring two variables.
       //You can also declare it as global.
       //but global variable must be initialized before creating toast otherwise you will get NPE and lead to you application crash
       String cText="Toast Message";
       int val=1;

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "vlaue is "+val, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

    }

});

    }
  public String getMessage(){
     return "Text from Function";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cText is out of scope. Either define it in the Top level or as a final variable before setting up the onClickListener.

You should learn the java basics about variables before diving head first into android, that will help you a lot. I can recommend the Head First Java book for that.

Answer (score 0):

`cText` sounds like a character sequence or at the least some kind of text. Assuming that its a character sequence or String: yes you can use it. 
Additionally you can also [customize](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109735/Toast-A-User-Notification) your toast notification.

Answer (score 0):

Declare cText with a class scope. setTextvalue() sets the string value. On Button click call displayValue() to display the toast message with the value set to cText.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String cText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setTextvalue();
Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           displayValue(); 
    }

});


    }
public void setTextvalue()
 {
      cText="hello";
 }
 public void displayValue()
 {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cText.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String message = "hello";
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
String strMessage = tv.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. I know that question was asked a while ago, however, it might be useful for someone else. That helped me to put the desired variable inside a Toast message.

```
   public void clickMeButton(View view) {
    EditText nameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);

   Toast.makeText(this,nameEditText.getText().toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```